# Kivy button (relative layout) no text on it

Tags: python, button, text, kivy

So this is my noob code and problem - there is no text on buttons in . Why? If I add label text is still not displayed.
In Carousel class text is added normally...
Only one workaround I found is to add Label on top of button (but I don't like this idea)

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.carousel import Carousel

Builder.load_string('''

<MainClass>:
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "y": .85}
        Button:
            text: "saasas"
            on_press: root.next()
        Button:
            text: "saasas"
        Button:
            text: "PREV"
            on_press: root.prev()

<Carousel>:
    size_hint: 1, .6
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Asas"
        Button:
        Button:
    GridLayout:
        cols:2
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:
        Button:

''')

class Add(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MainClass(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        RelativeLayout.__init__(self)
        self.car = Carousel()
        self.add_widget(self.car)


    def next(self, *args):
        print('next')

    def prev(self, *args):
        pass

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainClass()
Test().run()
```

I have no idea why this happen ...

Here is actual look of this window:

[image]

Comment: Do any of your buttons have text?

Comment: Yes. Button in Carousel class have
`Button:
            text: "Asas"`

Comment: And you can see the actual buttons in MainClass?

Comment: you can use http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.modules.inspector.html#module-kivy.modules.inspector, kivy Inspector to check the text property while the app is running, migh help you find the problem.